# Python/Sympy: solve equations with different values

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to solve these three equations:

```
a1 + a2 = b1
a2 + a3 = b2
b1 + b2 = c1
```

I generate values for three variables that are chosen randomly (disallowing the combination b1, b2, and c1), so I might have a1 = 5, a3 = 10, and c1 = 100, so I can solve that equation with sympy.

My problem is that I can't seem to transfer the random input to the sympy part of the code and loop over it.

```
a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, c1 = symbols('a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 c1')
solve([a1.subs(a1, 5) + a2 - b1, a2 + a3.subs (a3, 10) - b2, b1 + b2 - c1.subs (c1, 100)], (a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, c1))
```

This works when I assume a1, a3 and c1 as I mentioned in my example, but I choose those variables randomly beforehand. I've tried to create for-loops depending on which variables were chosen, but there are too many possible combinations of three variables, so I gave up.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you are expecting to get and what you have tried? Are you trying to tell sympy the values of `a1`, `a3` and `c1`?

Comment: If I understand correctly: Mark, you want to randomly pick three out of the six variables and give only those three numeric values, then have sympy solve for the remaining three?

Comment: @DavidZ: yes, that's what I am trying to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've correctly understood what you're asking, you can use Sympy's `linsolve` function to solve the equations symbolically first, then substitute in numbers afterwards. The key step is to tell `linsolve` which variables you want to solve for. I suggest using `set`s to separate the variables you're solving for from the ones you want to plug in values for. You might declare your variables like this:

```
all_vars = symbols('a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 c1')
# randomly choose which variables will have values
plug_in_for_vars = ...
solve_for_vars = tuple(set(all_vars) - set(plug_in_for_vars))
```

Then you can define your equations

```
equations = [a1 + a2 - b1, a2 + a3 - b2, b1 + b2 - c1]
```

and pass them and the chosen variables to `linsolve`

```
solution = linsolve(equations, solve_for_vars)
```

Then you can plug in the chosen values.

```
solution.subs({variable: value(variable) for variable in plug_in_for_vars})
```

Of course `value(variable)` is a proxy for whatever you do to determine the numeric values you want to plug in.

Comment: Hi, I took me quite a while to get this done, but now it works. I had some trouble with the part where the randomly chosen variables are removed from the tuple containing all variables. For some reason, nothing worked, so in the end, I put both sets in a list and used 'del' to remove the three variables. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Well, that's definitely not the ideal way to do it, but whatever works for you I guess. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 19 different ways to do this, so it's not too bad to just do this symbolically to see all possibilities:

```
from sympy import symbols, subsets, solve, Dict
v = a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, c1 = symbols('a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 c1')
eqs = (a1 + a2 - b1, a2 + a3 - b2, b1 + b2 - c1)
# we will not assign b1,b2,c1 so we will never solve for a1,a2,a3
ignore = set(v[:3])
for i in subsets(v, 3):
    if set(i) != ignore:
        subs = set(v)-set(i)
        sol = solve(eqs,i,dict=True)[0]
        print('replace',subs,'solve for',set(sol),':\n\t', sol)
```

The output is

```
replace {b2, c1, a3} solve for {a2, a1, b1} :
    {a1: a3 - 2*b2 + c1, a2: -a3 + b2, b1: -b2 + c1}
replace {c1, a3, b1} solve for {a2, b2, a1} :
    {a1: a3 + 2*b1 - c1, a2: -a3 - b1 + c1, b2: -b1 + c1}
replace {b2, a3, b1} solve for {a2, c1, a1} :
    {a1: a3 + b1 - b2, a2: -a3 + b2, c1: b1 + b2}
replace {a2, b2, c1} solve for {a1, a3, b1} :
    {a1: -a2 - b2 + c1, b1: -b2 + c1, a3: -a2 + b2}
replace {a2, c1, b1} solve for {b2, a1, a3} :
    {a1: -a2 + b1, a3: -a2 - b1 + c1, b2: -b1 + c1}
replace {a2, b2, b1} solve for {c1, a1, a3} :
    {a1: -a2 + b1, a3: -a2 + b2, c1: b1 + b2}
replace {a2, c1, a3} solve for {b2, a1, b1} :
    {a1: -2*a2 - a3 + c1, b1: -a2 - a3 + c1, b2: a2 + a3}
replace {a2, b2, a3} solve for {a1, b1} :
    {a1: -a2 - b2 + c1, b1: -b2 + c1}
replace {a2, a3, b1} solve for {b2, a1, c1} :
    {a1: -a2 + b1, b2: a2 + a3, c1: a2 + a3 + b1}
replace {a1, b2, c1} solve for {a2, a3, b1} :
    {a2: -a1 - b2 + c1, a3: a1 + 2*b2 - c1, b1: -b2 + c1}
replace {a1, c1, b1} solve for {a2, b2, a3} :
    {a2: -a1 + b1, a3: a1 - 2*b1 + c1, b2: -b1 + c1}
replace {b2, a1, b1} solve for {a2, c1, a3} :
    {a2: -a1 + b1, a3: a1 - b1 + b2, c1: b1 + b2}
replace {a1, c1, a3} solve for {a2, b2, b1} :
    {a2: -a1/2 - a3/2 + c1/2, b1: a1/2 - a3/2 + c1/2, b2: -a1/2 + a3/2 + c1/2}
replace {b2, a1, a3} solve for {a2, c1, b1} :
    {a2: -a3 + b2, b1: a1 - a3 + b2, c1: a1 - a3 + 2*b2}
replace {a1, a3, b1} solve for {a2, b2, c1} :
    {a2: -a1 + b1, b2: -a1 + a3 + b1, c1: -a1 + a3 + 2*b1}
replace {a1, c1, a2} solve for {b2, a3, b1} :
    {a3: -a1 - 2*a2 + c1, b1: a1 + a2, b2: -a1 - a2 + c1}
replace {a2, b2, a1} solve for {c1, a3, b1} :
    {b1: a1 + a2, c1: a1 + a2 + b2, a3: -a2 + b2}
replace {a2, a1, b1} solve for {b2, a3} :
    {a3: -a2 - b1 + c1, b2: -b1 + c1}
replace {a2, a1, a3} solve for {b2, c1, b1} :
    {b1: a1 + a2, b2: a2 + a3, c1: a1 + 2*a2 + a3}
```

If you want to see values, you can do `Dict(sol).subs(dict(zip(subs, (1,2,3))))` where `1,2,3` are the values you want to use:

```
Dict(sol).subs(dict(zip(subs, (1,2,3))))
{b1: 3, b2: 4, c1: 7}
```